# The last imported style is still present in the next React route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, webpack-dev-server

So I'm using `React`, `webpack-serve` and `less-loader` and I have 2 very simple pages which load a different style file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import 'less/index.less';

class IndexPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>qqwdqddddeeewd</div>)
    }
};

export default withRouter(IndexPage);
```

Both pages are importing a different less file, but when switching from the 1st page to the 2nd the style from the 1st page still remains in the 2nd page. (the `import` creates a `<style></style>` in the page)

What can I do to avoid that? How to do to have the 2nd page only having its imported style?

Comment: Please post your router config and other component as well. Why do you need withRouter anyway, if you have only two routes and they are probably the top level components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline style https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html. However according to React Doc [CSS classes are generally more efficient than inline styles.](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html#are-inline-styles-bad)

So, you can use nesting, and style inside a wrapper for each component.

```
class IndexPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (<div id="index">qqwdqddddeeewd</div>)
    }
};
```

Then in your index.less

```
#index {
// style here for index page elements
}
```